# Estimate Simulation time in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matlab code which performs operations on matrices for  example multiply one matrix by the other and then do some processing on the result. The size of my matrices are 10000*10000. So, is there a way to know how long will the simulation take or even a percentage complete of the simulation. As I am running the simulation on a server via terminal and I just have the terminal screen and I don't know whether is it running or where is it at.

Thanks.

Comment: You could time the program for smaller matrices and then extrapolate the estimated runtime complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to address this issue is to put several lines into your code that display where the simulation has got to.

For example, if you have several separate stages in your workflow, you can add lines such as

```
% Code to analyse the widget.

fprintf('Completed analysing the widget.')

fprintf('Now processing the results.')

% Code to process the results.
```

If you have an iterative process in a loop, you can add code such as:

```
for i = 1:n

    fprintf('Now starting stage %d', i)

    % Code to do stage i

    fprintf('Completed stage %d', i)

end
```